# dplyr + adding replicated vector via 'mutate'

Tags: r

I want to add a vector of variables to a dataframe, repeated within a given group of variables. There's got to be an easy way to do this within dplyr notation (I'd rather not have to do a match() statement)

Data:

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)

data <- data.frame(
    date = seq(as.Date('2014-11-01'), length = 30, by = '1 day'))   

data$day <- weekdays(as.Date(data$date))
data$week <- week(as.Date(data$date))
```

Now, for each week breakout, I want to add a number from a pre-specified vector (I'm trying to break apart the month into weekly percentages that sum to 1):

```
weekly_vector <-  c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1)
```

The idea is that I want the first element of this vector --0.1-- appended to Week 44, the second element to Week 45, and so on.

but something like:

```
data <- data %>% group_by(week) %>% mutate(perc = weekly_vector)
```

doesn't work: Error: impossible to replicate vector of size 5

How would I replicate the vector elements by the weekly breakout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign `weekly_vector` to the column `perc` for each subset of `data`, which is not what you want to do. What you want is to pick one element of `weekly_vector` for each week, and the assign this unique value to the `perc` column in `data`. One way to do this is via `left_join` by joining data with a data frame containing each week and the corresponding `perc` value.

```
data %>% left_join(data.frame(week = unique(data$week), perc = weekly_vector))
```

But you don't necessarily need `dplyr` here. You can for example just do

```
data$perc <- weekly_vector[factor(data$week, labels ="")]
```

Comment: Perfect... there's so many arguments to dplyr, I suppose I should re-read the documentation. Quick question: why do you need to specify "data.frame" in the left_join approach?

Comment: I just created the data frame to join data with inside the `left_join` function. You could do it outside that and store it in a separate variable if you prefer. `left_join` takes two data frames as arguments and then joins them. Since we are using the pipe operator, the first one is `data`