# R invalid subscript type double

Tags: r

I have sample data as shown below

```
Die     Device      Id      Vg     W   L 
  1     Device1       1       0    10   1 
  1     Device1     1.2     0.1    10   1 
  1     Device1     1.3     0.2    10   1
  1     Device2       1       0    10   2
  1     Device2     1.2     0.1    10   2 
  1     Device2     1.3     0.2    10   2
  1     Device3       1       0    10   3
  1     Device3     1.2     0.1    10   3 
  1     Device3     1.3     0.2    10   3
```

dput output:

```
data_tidy <- structure(list(Die = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Device = c("Device1", 
"Device1", "Device1", "Device2", "Device2", "Device2", "Device3", 
"Device3", "Device3"), Id = c(1, 1.2, 1.3, 1, 1.2, 1.3, 1, 1.2, 
1.3), Vg = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.2), W = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), L = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("Die", "Device", "Id", "Vg", 
"W", "L"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I am using the following piece of code to interpolate the value of `Vg` at specified `Id`.

```
data_tidy %>% group_by(Die,Device) %>% 
    mutate(Vt=approx(x=log10(Id), y=Vg, xout=log10(3e-8*W/L))$y)
```

I get an error saying

> Error: invalid subscript type 'double'

I am surprized because I was able to compile this code a few days ago without any errors. I had also discussed the code on the forum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513965/using-approx-function-on-grouped-data-in-r). I am not sure what is the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Id somewhere is zero in your data?

Comment: I am running the code on the sample data above where Id is not 0 but I still get the error.

Comment: i am not getting any such error with your code and data

Comment: I tried is again just now after reading your comment. I get the same error. Don't know what's going on here.

Comment: No i think you are not. See below answer.

Comment: I figured out that it works if I assign data_tidy<-setDT(data_tidy). However I am not sure why I cannot get it to work as a dataframe.

Comment: @beeprogrammer, I have had this error generated several times in the past. I've noticed that it usually occurs when I re-run a piece of code that have been executed before. The error is eliminated when the existing data frame is removed from environment and code is run again.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is you are trying to do the following if we break the code.

`Vt` is

```
Vt=approx(x=log10(data_tidy$Id),y=data_tidy$Vg,
xout=log10(3e-8*(data_tidy$W)/(data_tidy$L)))
```

This gives `Vt` as

```
> Vt
$x
[1] -6.522879 -6.522879 -6.522879 -6.823909 -6.823909 -6.823909 -7.000000 -7.000000
[9] -7.000000

$y
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Now with combined code i think you are trying to access `x` instead of `y`

```
> data_tidy%>%
+     group_by(Die,Device)%>% #Die is numeric, Device is factor
+     mutate(Vt=(approx(x=log10(Id),y=Vg,xout=log10(3e-8*W/L)))$x)
Error: invalid subscript type 'double'
```

You are trying to subscript a list by a subscript of type double inside mutate which is causing this issue. If you want `x` element of `Vt` to mutate. Use

```
data_tidy%>%
    group_by(Die,Device)%>% #Die is numeric, Device is factor
    mutate(Vt=(approx(x=log10(Id),y=Vg,xout=log10(3e-8*W/L)))[["x"]])
```

This should work.

Comment: I do not want x element of Vt but the y element of Vt. As also evident from the code that I am trying to determine the value of Vt when Id=3e-8*W/L. However if I use [["y"]] instead of $y to index y value it seems to work. I am not sure why $y seems to work for you but not for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution here using single scripts:

https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1554

```
dplyr::mutate(df, newColumn = someVariable$'a')
```